# Magento 1.9 authorize.net issue after update PATCH_SUPEE-11085

Tags: magento-1.9, error, payment-methods, authorize.net

I have updated the PATCH_SUPEE-11085_CE_1.14.4.0_v1-2019-02-28-05-21-55.sh with zero error. After I tried to pay with credit card showing the below.

```
Gateway error: The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.
```

I checked the gateway URL, Payment Update URL. Also, I tried the DPM method the same error occurred.

Now, The Authorized.net payment process not working on my site. Please help me to fix this.